# How to change fontSize for dataLabels?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I do not see in [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/pie/) any mention how to adjust `fontSize` of dataLabels.

dataLabels do not have any mention about font size:

```
    dataLabels: {
        offset: 0,
        minAngleToShowLabel: 10
    },
```

It's not possible?

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
        series: [4, 7, 3, 45, 32, 53],
        options: {  
                expandOnClick: true,

                dataLabels: {
                    minAngleToShowLabel: 50,
                    // offsetY: 1200,
                    style: { fontSize: '18px' } // this do not work!
                },  

                chart: {
                    width: 480,
                    type: 'pie',
                    
                },
                legend: {
                    // offsetX: 510,
                    fontSize: '16px',
                    height: 500,
                    width: 400,
                    horizontalAlign: 'right', 
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Some name',
                    style: {
                            fontSize: '20px',
                    },      
                },              
                labels: ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"],
                responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 480,
                options: {
                    chart: {
                    width: 480
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: 'right',
                        offsetY: 40,
                        fontSize: '16px',
                        
                    },
                            
                }
                }]

            },
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  components: {
    VueApexCharts
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ayx8ez9k/

Answer (score 4):

You can find a pretty good summary of your options here on this page: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/datalabels/

```
style: {
      fontSize: '14px',
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      colors: undefined
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply provide styling in CSS class.

```
  .apexcharts-pie-label{
    font-size:25px;
    }
```